# AI Text Generator returning AttributeError: can't set attribute

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory

I use library aitextgen from here https://github.com/minimaxir/aitextgen in google colab to make a text generator model, but when I run "ai.train" it became an error. Any suggestion to fix this? Thanks for your help

Here's the code

```
ai.train(file_name,
     line_by_line = False,
     from_cache = False,
     num_steps = 3000,
     generate_every = 1000,
     save_every = 1000,
     save_gdrive = False,
     learning_rate = 1e-3,
     fp16 = True, 
     batch_size = 1,
     )
```

And it's the error message

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-e611ad4fbd0c> in <module>
----> 1 ai.train(file_name,
      2          line_by_line = False,
      3          from_cache = False,
      4          num_steps = 3000,
      5          generate_every = 1000,

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aitextgen/aitextgen.py in train(self, train_data, output_dir, fp16, fp16_opt_level, n_gpu, tpu_cores, max_grad_norm, gradient_accumulation_steps, seed, learning_rate, weight_decay, adam_epsilon, warmup_steps, num_steps, save_every, generate_every, n_generate, loggers, batch_size, num_workers, benchmark, avg_loss_smoothing, save_gdrive, run_id, progress_bar_refresh_rate, freeze_layers, num_layers_freeze, use_deepspeed, **kwargs)
    673 
    674         # Wrap the model in a pytorch-lightning module
--> 675         train_model = ATGTransformer(self.model, train_data, hparams, self.tokenizer)
    676 
    677         # Begin training

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aitextgen/train.py in __init__(self, model, dataset, hparams, tokenizer)
     19     def __init__(self, model, dataset, hparams, tokenizer):
     20         super(ATGTransformer, self).__init__()
---> 21         self.model, self.dataset, self.hparams, self.tokenizer = (
     22             model,
     23             dataset,

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   1311                     buffers[name] = value
   1312                 else:
-> 1313                     super().__setattr__(name, value)
   1314 
   1315     def __delattr__(self, name):

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I've tried to change the version of torch, pytorch-lightning, and aitextgen but still error.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, providing a snippet of your code generating the error would be very useful as also knowing the versions of python and involved libraries. Happy 2023

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i've added the code and link of the library used. i use python 3 in google colab

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, what I did is:

```
!pip install pytorch-lightning==1.2.10
```

and it worked again